# how we can test Production Push notifcation on testflight?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apn

I have tested push notifications using developer certificate and it is working well but when i tried through production certificate and make a build with IOs app store deployment profile and upload to itunes for testflight internal testing. Moreover, i am not getting any push notification using testflight build.so how we can test production apple  push notification using testflight. So is there any possibility to test that notification before app published?.

Comment: you changed the server url to production ?

Comment: yes i already did but not getting

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can test push notifications before publishing the app using testflight builds. Few things you have to do before uploading the build:

1. Make sure you have generated production push SSL certificate and replaced the development push certificate with the newly generated production certificate on the server.
2. Make sure you have created/renewed distribution provisioning profile
   after you have generated production push certificate.
3. Use newly created/updated provisioning profile for the build you are
   uploading to the iTunesConnect.

If you did all this steps, you should be able to test push notifications from testflight builds, at least, this is the way I do test push notifications. Hope, this was helpful.

Comment: okay i did all the thing but if u are telling this ll be helpful then  i ll do one more time and re verify it.

Comment: try with creating certificates again and then test. Sometimes i faced this same issue. Also don't forget to change the .pem file(created with new production certificate) on server.

Answer (score 0):

Create **Adhoc Distribution Profile** from member center and take **ipa file** or you can use **testflight**.

You can test production certificate using adhoc.

Comment: even i created Adhoc Distribution Profile from member center and Tried to check production certificate push notifcation but not getting any notificationa ...are u sure it is possibility to get notification with adhoc profile??

Comment: Yes. It is possible and i tested in my projects also.

Comment: whatever steps u told me ..i just now followed but not getting any notification ...i created ipa with adhoc profile now ... @RJV Kumar